# Extracting data from google worksheet and selenium to write to webpage

Tags: selenium, worksheet

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from selenium import webdriver
import time

sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range="TAX!A1:E5").execute()
data = result.get('values')

list = []

for i in user_input:

    if i == 1:
        list.append(data[0])

    elif i == 2:
        list.append(data[1])

    elif i == 3:
        list.append(data[2])

    elif i == 4:
        list.append(data[3])

    elif i == 5:
        list.append(data[4])

    else:
        print('ERROR')

print(list)
print(('The length of list is: ' + str(len(list)))
print(range(len(list)))

driver = webdriver.Safari()

try:
    driver.get('some_website')

    for i in range(len(list)):

        search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('some_search_box')
        search_box.click()
        search_box.send_keys(list[i])
        cart_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('some_button')
        cart_button.click()

#print any exceptions such as element not found error, then close browser
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('driver closing on error')
    driver.close()
```

---

This is what I get:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '5', '6'], ['6', '4', '2', '3', '4']]
```

The length of list is : 3
range(0, 3)

---

The user input one or more options, and depending on that option it extracts data from sheet that could be multiple values. This how the list forms.

It is working as it should but there is one problem. it types the whole first array in search box (['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']) but i want it to search with each element.
I want the length of list to be 14 not 3, and I don't know how to solve this.

Is it possible to append to list and get one array on the output, the length of array is depending on user input?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    # Add this line to loop through the second element and so forth.
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        # Fix this one
        search_box.send_keys(list[i][j])
```

Just use a for for loop to go through a 2d list.

You can also simplify the top bit

```
if i<=5 and i >=1: 
    list.append(data[i-1]) 
else: 
    print('ERROR')
```

Comment: Fantastic! That did the trick. Not sure about the simplifying the top bit when there is multiple inputs. But there is probably a better way than this not shure what it is yet. Thank you very much!

Comment: Wait, I see now. That worked also. TY so much.